# MongoDB retrieving extra fields

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongoose

I seem to be constructing my mongoDB query wrong but I'm not sure how. I'd like to only get the username fields of my users database but I am getting all the fields.

My console log command (containing my query) is: `console.log(JSON.stringify(Meteor.users.find({}, {_id: 0, password: 0}).fetch()));`

This is the result of using the command:

```
[{"_id":"HF3o6oSNx2Qrg54Fc","username":"aaaa","password":"aaaapassword"},
{"_id":"H9r7qEcX7cF8kRSEf","username":"bbbb","password":"bbbbpassword"},
{"_id":"nhWZNNmBcNJuS5MFv","username":"cccc","password":"ccccpassword"}]
```

I have the exact same issue occurring on the server side.

My understanding from:
[How to select a single field in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589113/how-to-select-a-single-field-in-mongodb)
and http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/

is that if I used a 0 the given field would be excluded from the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're usage of `find` is a bit off.

```
Meteor.users.find({}, {fields: {_id: 0, password: 0}})
```

Check [the docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find) for more info.

Comment: Thanks will accept asap.