# MongoDB fetch data from another field

Tags: sql, mongodb

i have a code in sql in a java envirnmen which is looks like 
TXT='121';

```
SELECT NAME FORM TAB WHERE ID=TXT;
```

TXT is define as a '121' which is VARCHAR2 datatype 
can i convert this query into MongoDB where i can the ID from another variable 
thnks in advance 
can i do this like

```
db.Collection_name.find({'NAME':1},{'ID':'.....values.....'});
```

can it is possible ?

Comment: Tutorial in the core documentation [Limit Fields to Return from a Query](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select a single field in MongoDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589113/how-to-select-a-single-field-in-mongodb)