# select only two fields in mongodb using monk

Tags: mongodb, monk

My document has around 20 fields in it

I want to select only 2 fields and ignore other fields

I tried the below code as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589113/how-to-select-a-single-field-in-mongodb)

```
collection. find({}, {  Name: 1, District: 1,_id:0},{limit:5}, function (e, docs) {
        res.json(docs);
    });
```

But its returning all fields. I want to get only name and district.

**i.e I have Name,District,Country,Pincode,PhoneNumber, emailId,photo and many other fields. I want to select only Name and District.**

P.S I am looking for ways other than giving all other field names as 0

I am using **Monk**

Comment: Which library? I suspect you also mean that either "Name" or "Distrinct" here actually has embedded fields you are trying to exclude, which is not clearly stated without an example.

Comment: I am using Monk. I have added the details in the question now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using [Monk](https://github.com/Automattic/monk#signatures), pass the fields to select as a string containing space-delimited field names, using a `-` prefix to exclude a field.

```js
collection.find({}, 'Name District -_id', function (e, docs) {
    res.json(docs);
});
```

You can also pass the field selections as an array of strings:

```js
collection.find({}, ['Name', 'District', '-_id'], function (e, docs) {
    res.json(docs);
});
```

Comment: I am getting this error  `fn should be a function`
should i add it after all the options?

Comment: @vignesh Yes, the callback function parameter always goes last.

Comment: I used this query and its throwing the same error 
`collection. find({} ,  { limit: 5 ,skip:5*buffer}, 'Name -_id', function (e, docs) {
  res.json(docs);
    });`

Comment: @vignesh You really shouldn't be changing your question after you've gotten an answer to your original question.  Options go after the field selection parameter and before the callback.

Comment: ok I have accepted the answer thanks.

i thought a new question would be a repetition of this

Comment: is it possible to select name age and _id and eliminate the rest?

Comment: This answer does not include the "limit" part.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
db.<collection>.find({},{"Name": 1, "District": 1})
```

Answer (score 1):

While using [monk](https://github.com/Automattic/monk#signatures), I prefer something like this

```
query={'userType':'crew'}; // condition to select users
query2=['_id' ,'firstname' , 'lastname'] ; //Array, Limit the fields to retrieve 
collection.find(query,query2, function(error,crew){
    if(error)
        response.send(error)
    else {
        response.send(crew);
    }
});
```

Please note that it is better to include "_id" otherwise ng-repeat will cause issues and you will have to iterate it using $index .
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
collection.find().select('field1,field2').then((data) =>{res.send(data)})
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts. That's especially important when there's already an accepted answer that's been validated by the community. Under what conditions might your approach be preferred? Are you taking advantage of new capabilities?