# To find the _id of document other than during insertion

Tags: python, mongodb

I have created several documents and inserted into Mongo DB.I am using python for the same . Is there a way where in I can get the _id of a particular record?
I know that we get the _id during insertion. But if i need to use it at a lateral interval is there a way I can get it by say using the find() command?

Comment: Of course you can :)

Comment: @SergiuZaharie Please elaborate

Comment: what are you trying to do? Each document has an _id, of course you can search for a document and display its _id.

Comment: `_id` will be returned as part of the document when you use `find`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589113/how-to-select-a-single-field-in-mongodb This link provides the option to return selective fields. Is there any option to retrieve only the id field?  @dirn

Comment: `Collection.findOne(query,{fields: {_id: 1}})` will get you just the `_id`

Answer (score 0):

You can user the projection to get particular field from the document like this

db.collection.find({query},{_id:1})  this will return only _id

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/

Answer (score 0):

In python, you can use the **[`find_one()`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one)** method to get the document and access the `_id` property as following:

```
def get_id(value):
    # Get the document with the record:
    document = client.db.collection.find_one({'field': value}, {'_id': True})
    return document['_id']
```

Answer (score 0):

When you insert the record, you can specify the _id value. This has added benefits for when you're using ReplicaSets as well.

```
from pymongo.objectid import ObjectId

client.db.collection.insert({'_id': ObjectId(), 'key1': value....})
```

You could store those Ids in a list and use it later on if your requirement for needing the _id occurs immediately after insert.