# How to get critarea result with specific key and value from collection of mongo database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Lets suppose, we have collection called **posts**

```
    {
    "_id": ObjectId("5146bb52d8524270060001f3"),
    "post_text":"This is a sample post" ,
    "user_name": "mark",
    "post_privacy": "public",
    "post_likes_count": 0
    },
   {
    "_id": ObjectId("5146bb52d8524270060001f4"),
    "post_text": "This is a sample post",
    "user_name": "pramod",
    "post_privacy": "public",
    "post_likes_count": 0
   }
```

lets assume we have same table in mysql.
I want same query of sql result into mongo.

query is: `select post_likes_count from posts where user_name="mark";`
How we can get same result in mongodb?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select a single field in MongoDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589113/how-to-select-a-single-field-in-mongodb)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Ans:**

```
db.posts.find({user_name:"mark"});
```

[mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OtsrRaqvcIB)