# MongoDb, find specific objects, nested values matching specific value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, subquery

```html
db.Rooms.find({"name" : "room3"}).pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("57f50608ace5ceb9af033528"),
        "name" : "room3",
        "userData" : {
                "user" : ObjectId("57f4d142ace5ceb9af033521"),
                "date" : "Wed Oct 05 2016 15:54:16 GMT+0200"
        },
        "active" : true,
        "users" : [
                {
                        "uid" : ObjectId("57f383a6ace5ceb9af033511")
                },
                {
                        "uid" : ObjectId("57f4d142ace5ceb9af033521")
                }
        ],
        "messages" : [
                {
                        "msg" : "first test since statement ",
                        "time" : "Wed Oct 05 2016 15:55:26 GMT+0200",
                        "user" : ObjectId("57f383a6ace5ceb9af033511")
                },
                {
                        "msg" : "second test since statement ",
                        "time" : "Wed Oct 05 2016 15:57:35 GMT+0200",
                        "user" : ObjectId("57f4d142ace5ceb9af033521")
                },
                {
                        "msg" : "third test since statement ",
                        "time" : "Wed Oct 05 2016 15:58:11 GMT+0200",
                        "user" : ObjectId("57f383a6ace5ceb9af033511")
                }
        ]
}
```

i am quite new to Mongo, and i am having trouble solving this. actually i have tried on my own for half a day allready :(

What i want, is to find "ONLY" the messages, that a certain user has inserted..

This is my collection.

(if it looks messy, i will link to an image instead) 
[image as link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKV8w.png)

**What i want is to show:**
all the "msg" from the "user" with _id : ObjectId("57f383a6ace5ceb9af033511")

i hope that someone can guide me or even tell me if this collection is bad or anything..

thx ;)

Comment: Could you share the code you tried to access the msg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar Question asked before

[How to filter array in subdocument with MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15117030/how-to-filter-array-in-subdocument-with-mongodb)

For you question using aggregate function

```
db.Room.aggregate(
    { $unwind: '$messages'},
    { $match: {'messages.user': {$eq: ObjectId("57f383a6ace5ceb9af033511")}}},
    { $group: {_id: '$_id', list: {$push: '$messages.msg'}}}
```

Result :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57f50608ace5ceb9af033528"),
    "list" : [ 
        "first test since statement ", 
        "third test since statement "
    ]
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer.. it did what i wanted :) you are a time savior :P

Answer (score 0):

There is another question regarding this topic:

[How to select a single field in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589113/how-to-select-a-single-field-in-mongodb)

In the find method you can pass another object (except for the query) that tells what field(s) to return.

For you it would looks something like this:

```
db.student.find({"_id" : ObjectId("57f50608ace5ceb9af033528")}, {messages:1})
```

where `1` in `{messages:1}` = select the "messages" field.