# Extract only a field from Mongodb Query

Tags: mongodb

I have this collection

```
 db.Tratte.insert(
    {
    "TransportID":["9901","9903"],
    "StopsBy":[
     {"Station":"Roma Termini",
     "StopsAt":ISODate("2016-01-01T09:05:00Z"),
     "LeavesAt":ISODate("2016-01-01T09:25:00Z")},
      {"Station":"Napoli Centrale",
     "StopsAt":ISODate("2016-01-01T10:37:00Z"),
     "LeavesAt":ISODate("2016-01-01T10:52:00Z")},
     {"Station":"Salerno",
     "StopsAt":ISODate("2016-01-01T11:35:00Z")}]
    })
```

and I want to extract the date (and only the date) when the train leaves "Roma Termini".

I tried the following query, but in this way I obtain all the information.

```
db.Tratte.find({"TransportID":"9901"},
   { StopsBy: 
     { 
        $elemMatch: { "Station": "Roma Termini" } 
     } 
    }

)
```

How can I extract only the "LeavesAt" field related to "Roma Termini"?
Thanks

Comment: you may find what you want here, probably http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589113/how-to-select-a-single-field-in-mongodb

Comment: I tried to use projection and adding {"LeavesAt":1} at the end of the query doesn't change anything and if I write my query without the elemMatch operator and try do {"LeavesAt":1} I obtain all the "LeavesAt" info, but I want only that related to my request ("Roma" in this case)

Comment: Try this - `db.Tratte.find({"TransportID":"9901"}, {StopsBy: { $elemMatch: { "Station": "Roma Termini" } }, "StopsBy.LeavesAt": 1 })`

Comment: It works. Oh my gosh, I forgot to prepend StopsBy!! Thank you. In this way I obtain "StopsBy": ["LeavesAt": ISODate()].... Is there a way to obtain directly only the value ISODate?

Comment: @Alex please write as answer and I'll approve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
db.Tratte.find(
    {"TransportID":"9901"}, 
    {StopsBy: { $elemMatch: { "Station": "Roma Termini" } }, "StopsBy.LeavesAt": 1 }
)
```

You need to use the dot notation to go 'inside' the StopsBy document

Answer (score 1):

Use aggregate query -

```
db.Tratte.aggregate([
{$match: {"TransportID": "9901"}}, 
{$unwind: "$StopsBy"}, 
{$match: { "StopsBy.Station" : "Roma Termini" }}, 
{$project: {"StopsBy.LeavesAt": 1}} ])
```

Comment: It returns this error: Sintax error: missing : after property id @(shell):1:75