# SELECT column FROM table ORDER BY date ASC mongodb equivalent

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'd like to query mongodb with sql equivalent of:

```
SELECT column FROM table ORDER BY date ASC
```

I can get the full collection, but I want only one column. I am using pyMongo with python 3.x

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because stack overflow is not a SQL to MongoDB converter

Comment: I've put an SQL statement to help people understand, what I'm trying to achieve here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589113/how-to-select-a-single-field-in-mongodb

Comment: Thank you, that answers my question