# How to not select fields that not defined in a schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'd like to use one collection for two schemas
E.g:
Document in DB:

```
{
  "name":"John",
  "position":"CEO"
}
```

Schema `User`:

```
{
  "name" : String
}
```

Schema `Employee`:

```
{
  "name" : String,
  "position" : String
}
```

Nevertheless, when selecting a user (`User.findById()`) in the result I can see all the fields from the document, even not defined in the schema.
I don't want to disclose some fields in a stripped-down model at all so `select: false` for such fields is not what I'm looking for ...
Also, I'd like to prevent saving any fields not listed in a schema.

Is it possible to define a schema in such way?

Or I'm wrong and `select:false` is exactly what I'm looking for? :-)

I'm using Mongoose `5.0.14` but it is not a problem to update to the latest version if it would help.

I saw question [How to select a single field in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589113/how-to-select-a-single-field-in-mongodb), but I want ODM to do this for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select a single field in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589113/how-to-select-a-single-field-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. :)

```
var fields = Object.keys(yourSchema.paths).join(' ');

//and when execute a query
User.find({}).select(fields).exec(callback);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it not the way I'd like to solve it. In this case, I have to add `select` in every place where I invoke `find`. I want ORM to do this for me.

Comment: oh okay. It's ODM btw not ORM. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this in your schema

```
 MySchema.pre('find', function() {
    this.select(fileds);
});
```

Comment: fileds will like this "name email -password -_id"