# Best practice to retrieve specified data from mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection with this fixed structure:

[image]

By fixed structure I mean I just push Objects to the level arrays which are `starter` - `intermediate` and `advanced` as you see.

Now suppose you want to fetch `intermediate` array only, I can do it like this and it works fine:

```
const level = 'intermediate';
const motherModel = await db.Mother.findOne({});
const motherLevel = motherModel.cards[level]; // here we can get the specified level
```

This approach I need to retrieve all the data from database and save it to memory which may not be the best practice nor the fastest way because we only want to get the `intermediate` level right?

Is there any better ways to do this? or I'm totally wrong and I can be fine with this approach?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25589150/14389830

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select a single field for all documents in a MongoDB collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589113/how-to-select-a-single-field-for-all-documents-in-a-mongodb-collection)

Comment: Please guys note that I have no conditions to retrieve data. in the above links it's just like other samples on the net..

Comment: @SaraRee just project `.findOne({}, { ["cards."+level]: 1 })`