# Unable to select specific field for MongoDB find operation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to select only one field from a mongo document and print the value for it. I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25589150 which showed how we can achieve this. Below I have tried doing the same yet the entire document ends up getting printed.

```js
const mongoHost =
  'somemongourl'
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
const { MongoClient } = mongodb;

MongoClient.connect(
  mongoHost,
  { useNewUrlParser: true },
  async (error, client) => {
    if (error) {
      return console.log('Unable to connect to database!');
    }
    const db = client.db('cartDatabase');

    const values = await db
      .collection('cart')
      .find({ customer_key: 'c_1' }, { customer_key: 1, _id: 0 })
      .toArray();

    console.log(values);
  }
);
```

This is the output for example I got  :-

```
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("611b7d1a848f7e6daba69014"),
    customer_key: 'c_1',
    products: [ [Object] ],
    coupon: '',
    discount: 0,
    vat: 0,
    cart_total: 999.5,
    cart_subtotal: 999.5
  }
]
```

This is what I was expecting -

```
[
  {
    customer_key: 'c_1'
  }
]
```

Comment: The options parameter may require a top-level `projection` property. Try `{projection: {customer_key: 1, _id: 0}}` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot @B.Fleming this solves my question. Should I add this as an answer and accept it?

Comment: Also, I had tried searching a few other resources such as this - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/ . But could not find the mention of projection key and then assigning it the options as value. Where could I have found the documentation for this?

Comment: I'll add a full, proper answer with relevant documentation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard Node.js MongoDB driver requires a top-level `projection` property for the options parameter if you wish to project your documents. This would result in the second parameter of your `find()` call looking like this:

```
{ projection: { customer_key: 1, _id: 0 } }
```

This is indicated in the Node.js MongoDB driver API documentation, which is notably not a 1-to-1 match with the MongoDB shell API.

As of the time of this answer, you could find the `collection.find()` reference [here](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.2/classes/Collection.html#find). This reference shows the following method signature (again as of when this answer was written):

```
find(filter: Filter<WithId<TSchema>>, options?: FindOptions<Document>)
```

Following the `FindOptions` parameter takes us to [this reference page](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.2/interfaces/FindOptions.html), which details the various top-level options properties available for the `find()` method. Among these is the `projection` property in question.

In short, don't use the normal MongoDB documentation as a reference for your programming language's MongoDB driver API. There will often be disconnects between the two.