# can't get access to an object property

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, jwt

I'm using JWT token compare function to the user password in order to authenticate user login but after the mongoose query I cant get access to the user password

```
exports.login = async(req, res, next) => {
    
        const {email, password} = req.body

//checking if email and password exists
        if(!email || !password){
            return next(new AppError('Provide email and password', 400))
        } 

//checking if the user exists and password is correct
    try {   
        const user = await User.find({email}).select('+password')
        if(!user || !(await user.correctPassword(password, user.password))){
            return next(new AppError('Incorrect email and password', 401))
        }
//when everything is ok send the response to the client
        const token = SignToken(user._id)
        console.log(token);
        res.status(200)
            .json({
            status: 'success',
            token
            })
        } catch(err) {
            res.status(400).json({
                status: 'fail',
                message: err
            })
        }


}
```

After viewing the `user.password` in the console it is showing `undefined` so my `compare` function is not working. I'm fairly new to JWT

Comment: can you try showing the value of `console.log(user)`

Comment: Please share the implementation code of the method bellow
correctPassword(password, user.password)

Answer (score 0):

Your password is `undefined` as you made mistake while projecting fields by `User.find({email}).select('+password')`.In the mongoose the select method, you can't pass `"+"`. But if you want to skip any property you can use the `"-"` operator `select('-password)`.  And Also, you can't write like `select("-username password")`. Only the property name of the collection `'password'` is enough in the `select("password")` method to find the password.

Look that answer might be helpful for you.

[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51608395/13299299)

[Documentation Here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-select)