# How to set Grafana Panel Legend as Custom

Tags: grafana, dashboard

I'm trying to visualize MongoDB data with Grafana.
I want to custom the legend of panel to make it more intuitive.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZmZR.png)

That image is the panel I was working.

When I googled it, there is option to customize legend option, but in my grafana, I can't find it.
The image below is what I found in google.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0O6M.png)

Where can I customize legend in panel?

Comment: Image you found are off query to Prometheus. Not all query editor provide same options. Probably in case of mongo you are expected to modify what is shown in legend directly through query. [This might(?) help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589113/how-to-select-a-single-field-for-all-documents-in-a-mongodb-collection#25589150)